# Preserve onchange for a dropdown list when setting the value with Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, iphone, select

I have a dropdown list with a piece of code that is run when the value is changed:

```
<select name="SList" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'SList\',\'\')', 0)" id="SList">
```

Everything works fine when manually done. As an option is selected, the onchange code is called.

The problem begins when I try to change the selected value using a piece of Javscript. I want to be able to automatically change the selected option using JS, whilst still having the onchange code called, exactly as if done manually.

I try calling this:

```
form.SList.value = "33";
```

The right option is selected, but the onchange code does not get called. So then I try doing this:

```
form.SList.value = "33";
javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'SList\',\'\')', 0);
```

The right value is **not** selected and nothing happens.

FYI, the code is done in ASP.NET and Javascript.

What can I run to change the selected option whilst still calling the onchange code?

Comment: Any reason to tag this question with `iphone-sdk`?

Comment: It is for use in an iPhone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
form.SList.value = "33";
__doPostBack('SList','');
```

instead.

The `javascript:myfunction` tag is just for in-HTML use.

Comment: oh wow. I've been trying to get this to work for hours. That was one of the first things i tried, but with \' instead of just '. Thanks!!!